# android starting a service

Tags: android

I have read what I can find on here but I am still not really clear.
I write a package that has a main activity with a layout that just says what it is.
This calls startService().
In the service oncreate() an alarm intent is setup.
In the service onstart the intent is used in Alarm.setrepeating().
There is an AlarmReceiver, when the alarm is triggered it calls startService().

I install on Android phone and an icon is installed on the phone desktop.
Touch the icon and the layout appears and the service starts and establishes the alarm.

Now the bit that puzzles me.
How can I have the layout go away so that the desktop is usable while the service is running or waiting between alarms?   As far as I can tell if I use the back button the service is cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us your code? As far as I'm aware, services should stay, even when you switch to the homescreens. I've never had a service stop after I switch from the app. On the contrary, I've always been annoyed at how you have to STOP a service....

Comment: iAndroidOs - thanks for the reply.   I've discovered the problem was in the action string for the alarm.  A - where a _ should be!  Since your response confirmed that the service should stay pu it prompted me to look elsewhere so I've marked the answer arrow